# How to reset the windows look in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8

I have just installed Windows 8 in my system. I played around and made some icons smaller, larger and dragged then around. Is there any way of restoring the icons back to the default look?

Comment: Note to others reading this that refreshing Windows 8 uninstalls ALL desktop software (including games, Microsoft Office, Windows Live software, etc). After performing a system refresh you need to manually reinstall your software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could attempt in possibly refreshing your system.

Here is a [link](http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/windows-8-recovery.html) that will explain it to you and show you how.